# Failing to use VideoWriter for writing from a webcam capture

Tags: c++, opencv, runtime-error

I am trying to write the recording from my webcam into a file. For this purpose I am using the following code. I am getting an exit code of 2, all the time. Can someone help me figure out what is the problem?
I have previously used a similar function call to write frames from one video file into a new one, where it worked. Can't understand what is the problem in this case.

Code Snippet follows:

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

```
 cv::Mat frame;
 cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
 cv::BackgroundSubtractorGMG bg;
 bg.numInitializationFrames=120;
 bg.decisionThreshold = 0.95;
 bg.maxFeatures = 10; 

 double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
 CvSize frameSize;
 frameSize.height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
 frameSize.width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
 VideoWriter VW1("resultbuff.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'), fps, frameSize, 1);
 VideoWriter VW2("recordingbuff.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'), fps, frameSize, 1);
 VideoWriter VW3("finalResult.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'), fps, frameSize, 1);


 if (!VW1.isOpened())
 {
     std::cout << "!!! Output video could not be opened" << std::endl;
     return 2;
 }

 if (!VW2.isOpened())
 {
     std::cout << "!!! Output video could not be opened" << std::endl;
     return 3;
 }

 if (!VW3.isOpened())
 {
     std::cout << "!!! Output video could not be opened" << std::endl;
     return 4;
 }
```

As mentioned, the program exits with code 2.

Comment: double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); // returns 0 here. don't think it's supported with webcams. try a fixed number, like 25

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. Still exits with return code 2.

Comment: works for me (with a different codec). sure you got write permission ?

Comment: What Codec are you using? How can I find the correct codec to use?

Comment: try -1 instead of the FOURCC (there's no general solution here, it depends on your ffmpg, os, etc)

Comment: Okay, I found the answer. It was an error with the dlls. I was running the program in debug mode and the openCV dlls linked were for the release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer. It was an error with the dlls. I was running the program in debug mode and the openCV dlls linked were for the release mode.